# PdPS interlayer distance

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

PdPS is being considered as a layered material but when I look at its crystal structure it does not look like that. Fo example I could not figure out its interlayer distance. Does anyone familiar with this structure?

Comment: [Does this help](https://materials.springer.com/isp/crystallographic/docs/sd_1504123&ved=2ahUKEwjswKiTiNDnAhWDzTgGHV00CmcQFjACegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2PjcHsBXFvOuLzcWdWOJN6&cshid=1581649693643) or [this](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567740874007606) or [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264751437_The_structure_of_PdPS_and_the_crystal_chemistry_of_late_transition-metal_dipnictides_and_dichalcogenides&ved=2ahUKEwjswKiTiNDnAhWDzTgGHV00CmcQFjABegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2FyytCm5X0Bbf4yDRh3iWT&cshid=1581649693643)?

Comment: Could you post the information about the structure that you have trouble interpreting?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a visualisation that shows the layered structure of the material.

[image]

From the side:
[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, and it becomes possible to deduce the layer distance from the length of the unit cell vector a. Could you post a view of a single layer in a rotated view as well? S is yellow, P orange, and Pd bluish, right?

Comment: Yes, that's is the colour scheme.